# as3 dynamic Names for StageText / NativeText

Tags: actionscript-3

does anyone know how to dynamically assign a name to NativeText / StageText as i am trying to build a dynamic interface instead of hardcoding it in, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: solved this myself by doing this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848703/as3-object-values-nativetext

and setting the nt.name = to the dynamic instance name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is trying to return text values with NativeText a StageText wrapper. they will need to edit;

https://github.com/cantrell/StageTextExample/blob/master/src/NativeText.as

add a public get function -

```
public function get text():String {
return this.st.text;
}
```

then you can return the NativeText values normally -

```
nt.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep references to the dynamically created instances of StageText as you cannot get it by querying the display list (as it is not on display list). You can have the vector of of StageText

```
var m_vStageTextInstances:Vector<StageText>;
```

Then after you will just iterate over this vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code that does what you want inside the iterate-function

```
public class IterationTest extends Sprite {

    public function IterationTest() {
        createObjects();
        iterate();
    }

    private function createObjects():void {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            addChild(new TextField());
            addChild(new MovieClip());
        }
    }

    private function iterate():void {
        var numTextObjects:int = 0;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
            var child:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
            if (child is TextField) {
                //do your stuff here
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for posting a response, will have a look at this in more detail. but not sure this is going to help with StageText? http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html

Comment: oh sorry, thought you meant "native text fields" :o I'll see what I find^^

Comment: Thank you, for the help! :)

its type object NativeText, 

I've been playing with this - 

var nt:NativeText = NativeText(DisplayObjectContainer(getChildByName("INSTANCENAME"))); //INSTANCENAME = dynamic name been set
trace(nt.name); //traces INSTANCENAME
trace(nt.text);

but returns this error - 

1119: Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type NativeText.

i want to return the value of the instance name (not sure what to use).

Comment: the "Native" implementations are not part of the Flash display list so getChildByName can't work

Comment: thats correct but i am using a wrapper which allows you to, found the solution for this and posted it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848703/as3-object-values-nativetext