# as3 object values NativeText

Tags: actionscript-3

updated - if anyone is trying to return text values with NativeText a StageText wrapper. they will need to edit;

https://github.com/cantrell/StageTextExample/blob/master/src/NativeText.as

add a public get function -

```
public function get text():String {
return this.st.text;
}
```

then you can return the NativeText values normally -

nt.text

Comment: No direct solution for you but if you read the Solutions part of this page http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html it seems to indicate you can use a TextInput as an "accessor" to the underlying StageText.

Comment: Beware that this wrapper disposes the StageText on removing from stage event and then on adding to stage event it access the StageText instance. Which will cause: Error: Error #3694: The object was disposed by an earlier call of dispose() on it.

Comment: yes that is correct just experiencing this, what i did was edit the NativeText.as so onRemoveFromStage to st.visible = false; as a quick fix, you could also add a try/catch/finally too (to get rid of the disposed error).

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link in @shaunhusain's comment, and did some reading:

NativeText is a wrapper he wrote, you can look at the class on github:

https://github.com/cantrell/StageTextExample/blob/master/src/NativeText.as

If you read this class, you'll notice that it has a setter method for setting the text, but it does not define a getter.  This explains your error message:

> Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type NativeText

The logical solution is to add the getter method. If you read the comments on the blog post that @shaunhusain linked to, you'll see that someone else had this very same problem. This appears to have worked for them (I haven't tried it):

```
public function get text():String
{
    return this.st.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a getter in the way you described above worked for me :)

However, I do feel like I have to be cautious because maybe there's a reason Cantrell didn't put the getter method in.

Comment: great to hear, yes i added this same edit to the github repo - https://github.com/cantrell/StageTextExample/pull/9, if you want to return text this is the only way you are going to do it.